# How do I access the Azure blob services from client side?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Reading the documentation, I get the impression that blob services are just like any other web service.   How can I access the Block or Page upload services of blob data in Azure using any client side langauge, such as javascript, or python or Actionscript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a REST API. Read the documentation and implement a client (or grab one that already exists). I wrote a blog post about a bunch of them: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-storage-libraries-in-many-languages. It wasn't on the list then, but JavaScript is now covered in the Windows Azure Node.js SDK (`npm install azure`).